# Dwarf Fortress seeds on hand

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I see what kinds of seeds and how many of each I have on hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get accurate stock reports, you have to assign a bookkeeper on the nobles screen <kbd>n</kbd>. With the bookkeeper entry selected, you can press <kbd>s</kbd> to bring up the settings for the bookkeeper position. Here you set how much time your bookkeeper will spend updating stock records. The more precise you want the records, the more time the bookkeeper is going to have to spend counting things. Then you'll need to assign a meager office to your bookkeeper. Wait a little while and the stocks screen ( <kbd>z</kbd> ) should be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Stocks screen via the Status screen, which you can access using <kbd>z</kbd>.

The accuracy depends on your bookkeeper.

Comment: all I see is a number with a question mark next to it. I want to know what kinds of seeds I have.

Comment: The question mark means the bookkeeper has not kept accurate enough  track of stocks to know the exact amount of stuff. Give him an office and tell him to get to work.

Comment: @Shadur I answered this question before I had even ever played this game.